# Magnific pop-up synchronized with slider

Tags: flexslider, magnific-popup, slick.js

Just wondering if it is possible to synchronize Magnific pop-up with a slider(flexslider or slick, for example) so that when you change slide on Magnific pop-up the slider in the background also changes.

**EDIT**

```
$('.slick-slider').magnificPopup({
    delegate: '.slides:not(.slick-cloned) a',
    type: 'image',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    fixedContentPos: false,
    removalDelay: 350,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    gallery:{
        enabled: true,
        tCounter: '<span class="mfp-counter">%curr% of %total%</span>'
    },
    callbacks: {
        beforeClose: function() {
            $('.slick-slider').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(this.index - 1));

           // works better with the code bellow but sometimes gets stuck between 2 slides 
           $('.slick-slider').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(this.index));

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely possible. Here's an example using Slick.js.

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9dyh2yjt/1/)

### HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
    <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/1"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/1" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/2"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/2" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/3"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/3" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/4"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/4" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/5"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/5" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $carousel = $('.carousel');

    $carousel
        .slick()
        .magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            delegate: 'a:not(.slick-cloned)',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true
            },
            callbacks: {
                open: function() {
                    var current = $carousel.slick('slickCurrentSlide');
                    $carousel.magnificPopup('goTo', current);
                },
                beforeClose: function() {
                    $carousel.slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(this.index));
                }
            }
        });
});
```

### Dependencies

Also, make sure you pull in the dependencies for [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/).

### Update

- Accounts for cloned item created by Slick
- Updates Magnific Popup with current slide when opened via keyboard navigation

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me index - 1 doesn't seem to work as slick slider then goes to a slide before the one where I was on magnificPopup. So, if I remove - 1 and have just index on its own it goes to the right slider on exiting magnificPopup, but sometimes it gets stuck between 2 slides instead of going to the correct one. I have edited my question above so you see my code.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've updated my answer so Magnific Popup excludes the cloned item created by Slick. It also sets the correct image when opening Magnific Popup with keyboard controls.

Comment: Cool! Would it be possible to make slick slider change at the same time as magnificPopup? So when I exit magnificPopup slick slider is already showing me the image I was at on magnificPopup when I exited it.

Comment: [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api) has a `change` event which you can add similar to `beforeClose`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I have another question about Magnific Popup. Let me know if I should ask a separate question for this. I am working on a WordPress theme and I was wondering if there is a way of opening images in Magnific Popup which are inserted on a post body by the editor. So, any image I insert in a post through TinyMCE editor will open on Magnific Popup when clicked on the front end.

Comment: I'd start a new question. There are a few ways to approach this. Let me know once it's created and I'll add my approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Opened a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293573/magnific-popup-for-wordpress-post-body-images.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I am having an issue with the slick slider version and I was wondering if it's something you might be able to help with. At the moment I have 5 images on my slick slider and when I click on them they open nicely in Magnific Popup. However, if I scroll through all those 5 images on slick slider when I get to the sixth image which is my 1st image again I have noticed that it has a class of .slick-cloned, so if I click on it it doesnt open with Magnific Popup. I have tried quite a few things but noting seems to work.

Comment: @Madeirense you need to catch the click on the cloned element and delegate it to the original one. You'd need to put some unique element on your slides like data-id="1" .. which will be the same on the cloned ones and you could then do something like this:

Comment: @Madeirense
//- Handle cloned elements to open the correct popup
$('.slick-cloned a', element).on('click', (e) => {
  let slide = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.slide'),
      slider = $(slide).closest(this.selector),
      slideId = $(slide).data('id'),

      query = ``.slide:not(.slick-cloned)[data-id="${slideId}"]``,

      original = $(query, slider);

  $('a', original).click();

Answer (score 0):

And if you have multiple .carousel instances you can do like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/9dyh2yjt/98/

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('.carousel').each(function() {
    var gallery = $(this);
    gallery
    .slick()
    .magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      delegate: 'a:not(.slick-cloned)',
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      },
      callbacks: {
        open: function() {
          var current = gallery.slick('slickCurrentSlide');
          console.log(current);
          gallery.magnificPopup('goTo', current);
        },
        beforeClose: function() {
          gallery.slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(this.index));
        }
      }
    });
  });
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="carousel">
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/1"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/1" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/2"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/2" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/3"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/3" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/4"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/4" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/5"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/5" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/1"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/1" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/2"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/2" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/3"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/3" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/4"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/4" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="//satyr.io/1280x720/5"><img src="//satyr.io/600x400/5" width="600" height="400" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```