# Magnific Popup for Wordpress post body images

Tags: wordpress, post, tinymce, magnific-popup

I am working on a WordPress theme and I was wondering if there is a way of opening images in Magnific Popup which are inserted on a post body by the editor. So, any image I insert in a post through TinyMCE editor will open on Magnific Popup when clicked on the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different approaches to this question. I've outlined a couple below.

## Option 1

Filter the content and apply a HTML attribute that can be targeted with Magnific Popup.

We can [take a cue from this article](https://longren.io/add-rellightbox-to-all-images-embedded-in-a-wordpress-post/) and leverage [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) hook.

> The "the_content" filter is used to filter the content of the post
>   after it is retrieved from the database and before it is printed to
>   the screen.

### functions.php

Add the following to `functions.php`.

```
function prefix_content_gallery( $content ) {
    global $post;

    $pattern     = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
    $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 rel="lightbox" title="'.$post->post_title.'"$6>';
    $content     = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_content_gallery' );
```

### JS

```
$('.entry-content').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    delegate: '[rel="lightbox"]',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

[View Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeQgXP?editors=1010)

---

## Option 2

Another option would be to selectively assign a CSS class to links which should be part of the image gallery.

1. Add media to post and set "Link To" to "Media File" under Attachment Display Settings.

[image]

2. Edit the image after it has been inserted into the post.

[image]

3. Add a CSS class to the link which wraps the image.

[image]

### JS

```
$('.entry-content').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    delegate: '.entry-gallery',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

[View Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVrayX?editors=1010)

Comment: I really like the first approach. However, it's not working at all for me. I don't get any Javascript or PHP errors, it just doesn't seem to do anything.   The PHP function is supposed to wrap the post body images in a tags, right?

Comment: Are you linking to the media file when inserting into the post? See the 1st step in option 2 for reference. If so, is the `rel="lightbox"` being added to the markup? For the JS part, `.entry-content` is the containing element around `the_content()` output. Make sure that aligns with your markup.

Comment: I see.. Working now. Thanks a lot dude, you've been really helpful!

Comment: Just one other thing. Is it possible to also have this working with the featured image?

Comment: If the featured image lives outside `.entry-content`, you'll need to move up the DOM to an element that contains both featured and post images. Make sure to add `rel="lightbox"` to the link containing the featured image.

Comment: Alternatively, you can call Magnific Popup directly on elements containing `rel="lightbox"`. `$('[rel="lightbox"]').magnificPopup([...])`. Make sure to remove the delegate option.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry man, at the moment I am getting the post tile as caption when I open post body images with Magnific Popup. I would like to get the image caption instead. I have tried replacing $post->post-title for $post->post_excerpt but no luck.